# CakePHP: Undefined Index:

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Really Confused here. I keep getting an undefined index.

controller:

```
function makemodel($id = null) {
    $this->Make->id = $id;

    $makes = $this->Make->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
        'contain' => array('Makemodel' => array('Road'))
        )
    );

    $this->set(compact('makes'));
}
```

view:

im echoing. which coming from the array that should be correct $makes['Make']['MakeName']

I also tried $makes['Make'][0]['MakeName']

it states its having an issue at ['Make']

array:

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Make] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [url_make] => ford
                    [MakeName] => Ford
                    [MakeOrigin] => USA
                    [Summary] => 
                )`

```
        [Makemodel] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [ModelName] => Focus
                        [make_id] => 2
                        [Road] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [makemodel_id] => 2
                                        [RoadTypeID] => 1
                                        [name] => Dirt
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                        [makemodel_id] => 2
                                        [RoadTypeID] => 2
                                        [name] => Snow
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the array it'd be:

$makes[0]['Make']['id'] etc.

Comment: didnt think cakephp would be case sensitive on the column names. ['id] worked but ['MakeModel'] wouldnt so I made it all lower case and it worked. Thanks